# angularJS routing - Finding element positions on page

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, routes

I'm trying to do some translating of existing code functionality to angular and routing.

Currently, I have it such that mouse position tracks relative distance to some divs (each div counts as a 'color,' the closer the mouse, the brighter that color).

I found how to track mouse position in angular, now I'm having trouble getting element coordinates - specifically since the elements are part of the routed pages. I'm not sure if I need to use getBoundingClientRect and getElementBy[id/class/etc] to select the elements or if there is some other way that angular routing requires or would function better with.

edit - clarification: I can select elements on the routed page just fine... after the routed page loads. I'm scouring the documentation for a one-time ng-event that can find the element *after* the route loads. Currently, I can find things on page load (but before route loads), or I can try to bind it to something like mousemove (i.e. constantly re-evaluating the position of non-moving parts).

Comment: use angular.element() to get the element, read https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

Comment: I can target the element after the route page loads, but not before. I can find things that evaluate when the page loads, but I can't find an ng-event that evaluates after the route loads. Ideally I find some ng-event that _is not_ something that runs more than once (I could bind it to mousemove, but that would keep evaluating the positions of divs that do not move)